# How to deny access contains word?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to deny access for bots when they are visiting site with spam urls with word contains option.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_users [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

But its not working. Can you explain me why?

Comment: You probably want your rule like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]` but it should work.

Comment: im trying your solution

Comment: Make sure you also turn on engine. `RewriteEngine On` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the above code and Put only the following line of code at your `.htaccess` and it will do it for you :

```
RedirectMatch 403 option
```

this will redirect any request including  option to be forbidden

Comment: The way he's trying to do it is correct. You **can't** match a query string with mod_alias (RedirectMatch). Its not part of the URI.

Comment: No either way it **wont** see `option` because it's part of the query string. Have you read the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)